# Optimization Function Inside a Loop and Another Function

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to solve for optimal values repeatedly with different random values. So the minimize function is included inside a loop and a function, then I call that function. However, it always gives me different answer.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def Ln(theta): # Every loop tries to minimize this value
    error = Y - np.maximum(0, theta[0] + X.dot(theta[1:]))
    error_total = np.absolute(error).sum()
    return error_total
theta_true = np.array([-6,3,3,3])
Y = np.array(10)
def get_opt_x():
    for i in range(10):
        X = np.random.standard_normal([10,3]) # generate random values
        u = X[:,0]**2*np.random.standard_normal(10)
        Y_star = theta_true[0] + X.dot(theta_true[1:]) + u
        Y = np.maximum(0, Y_star)
        theta0 = np.ones(4)
        result = minimize(Ln, theta0, method='BFGS')
        print result.x
    return 
get_opt_x()
```

This is what it gives:

[image]

The correct answer is supposed to be different, since for every loop, a new set of random values are generated. If I get rid of the function, and just do the loop everything works fine:

```
for i in range(10):
    X = np.random.standard_normal([10,3])
    u = X[:,0]**2*np.random.standard_normal(10)
    Y_star = theta_true[0] + X.dot(theta_true[1:]) + u
    Y = np.maximum(0, Y_star)
    theta0 = np.ones(4)
    result = minimize(Ln, theta0, method='BFGS')
    print result.x
```

[image]

There must be something wrong with using minimize function inside a loop and another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `X` and `Y` within `get_opt_x()` are local to `get_opt_x()` and are *different* from `X` and `Y` in function `Ln`. The results from `get_opt_x()` are all the same because it is using the values from the last loop u ran (by getting rid of your function). To prove that try closing your session and run your first block of code before running the second block, you'll get an error saying `X` is not initialized.

**Solution:** 
pass `X` and `Y` as extra arguments to the `minimize` routine

```
def Ln(theta, X, Y): # Every loop tries to minimize this value
    error = Y - np.maximum(0, theta[0] + X.dot(theta[1:]))
    error_total = np.absolute(error).sum()
    return error_total

theta_true = np.array([-6,3,3,3])
Y = np.array(10)

def get_opt_x():
    for i in range(10):
        X = np.random.standard_normal([10,3]) # generate random values
        u = X[:,0]**2*np.random.standard_normal(10)
        Y_star = theta_true[0] + X.dot(theta_true[1:]) + u
        Y = np.maximum(0, Y_star)
        theta0 = np.ones(4)
        result = minimize(Ln, theta0, (X, Y), method='BFGS')
        print result.x
    return 

get_opt_x()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're defining the variable `Y` inside the function `get_opt_x` and then expecting it to be visible to the function `Ln`, which Python disallows.  When you remove the `get_opt_x` function, the value `Y` is then available in the global scope and thus visible to the `Ln` function.

You need to tell Python that `Y` is a global variable at the beginning of `get_opt_x`:

```
def get_opt_x():
    global Y
```